# New laravel routes not working on any method

Tags: laravel

My code for my controller:

```
class MobileLoginController extends Controller{
    public function SendMail(){
        echo 'test';
    }

    public function otherroute(){
        echo 'testotherroute';
    }
}
```

My web.php

```
Route::post('/mobilesendshopmail','MobileLoginController@SendMail');

Route::post('/mobiletestotherroute','MobileLoginController@otherroute');
```

I have added it too to `VerifyCsrfToken`

```
    protected $except = [
        '/mobilesendshopmail',
        '/mobiletestotherroute',
    ..]
```

Other routes are working, like the route for [`mobiletestotherroute`]

Whats is wrong?
But, if I put the content of route sendmail to route otherroute it works.

Comment: Could you share what kind of error you get ?

Comment: I got 419 , but i already added the route to VerifyCsrf

Answer (score 0):

> you may also exclude the routes by adding their `URIs` to the `$except`
>   property of the VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'mobilesendshopmail',
        'mobiletestotherroute',
    ];
}
```

Comment: can you check again my post question? I already added the routes to the VerifyCsrfToken :<

Comment: Try again without '/' in the beginning

Comment: I already tried, with /, without /, the entire url too, myurl.com/mobilesendshopmail

Comment: did you checked if \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class is loaded in your app\Http\kernel.php ?

Comment: yes i do, it was added. Here's the rough part, other routes are working, they have the same code to the new route that isn't working.

Comment: Yes , other post routes are working fine. What should i do?

Comment: I did php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear too, but to no avail

Comment: Could you add where and how you call your post routes and if possible a screen capture of php artisan route:list result

Comment: Could you add your blade files where you call theses POST routes ?

Comment: i dont return a view, i just echo a value. For example is this https://shop.sympies.net/api/v1/users/posts/testroute .

Comment: I mean how do you call these routes?  via form action OR ajax call or APIs ?

Comment: Just calling the routes via Https request calls, did you clicked the sample route link? https://shop.sympies.net/api/v1/users/posts/testroute

Answer (score 0):

So this is just some dumb situation im facing lol, the thing is I'm getting conflict with github, since when i check my local code for VerifyCsrf i have the route for /mobilesendshopmail, but when i pull to our production server, i got no pulling error, but my VerifyCsrf wasnt added, because it was listed on my .gitignore jeez.